# conditional operator if in latex

Tags: conditionals, programming

It is necessary to build a graph (vector diagram of a diode) and if the angle (\ Fi) is greater than 90, then all vectors will be equal to 0. I don’t understand how to use if in latex correctly.

\ usepackage {ifthen} connected, tried different variations, but always gives an error.

I would be very grateful for your help!

Here is an example of one of my attempts

```
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{I}} {\partial t}
$$

\begin{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\DV}{5}
\newcommand{\DI}{4}
\newcommand{\Fi}{80}
\newcommand{\Fii}{\Fi+7}
       \ifthenelse{\Fi < 90}
           {{\draw[->,blue] (0,0) -- ( {\DV*cos(\Fi)}, {\DV*sin(\Fi)}) node[right] {$\vec{V}$};
           \draw[->,red](0,0) --  ( {\DI*cos(\Fi -10)}, {\DI*sin(\Fi-10)}) node (A) {}node[below right] 
           {$\vec{I}(t)$};
          \draw[->,red](0,0) --  ( {\DI*cos(\Fii -10)}, {\DI*sin(\Fii-10)}) node (B) {}node[right] 
          {$\vec{I}(t+ {\small\Delta}t)$};
          \draw[->] (A.center) -- (B.center);
        \draw[->,ultra thin]    (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[below] {x}}

        {\draw[->,ultra thin]    (-6,0) -- (6,0)}
        
        
\end{circuitikz}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mispaired braces and missing path delimiters `;`. It becomes cleared when you properly indent/align your code. Also, don't leave blank lines between the branches `<true>` and `<false>` within `\ifthenelse{<cond>}{<true>}{<false>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz,ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \newcommand{\DV}{5}
  \newcommand{\DI}{4}
  \newcommand{\Fi}{67}
  \newcommand{\Fii}{\Fi+7}
  \ifthenelse{\Fi < 90}{%
    \draw[->,blue] (0,0) -- ( {\DV * cos(\Fi)}, {\DV * sin(\Fi)}) node[right] {$\vec{V}$};
    \draw[->,red]  (0,0) -- ( {\DI * cos(\Fi - 10)}, {\DI * sin(\Fi - 10)}) node (A) {} node[below right] {$\vec{I}(t)$};
    \draw[->,red]  (0,0) -- ( {\DI * cos(\Fii - 10)}, {\DI * sin(\Fii - 10)}) node (B) {} node[right] {$\vec{I}(t + {\scriptstyle\Delta}t)$};
    \draw[->] (A.center) -- (B.center);
    \draw[->,ultra thin] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[below] {x};
  }{
    \draw[->,ultra thin] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
  }
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! helped a lot